# How to use Multi Image picker with Flutter Image Compress?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have successfully implemented flutter multi image picker. But I want to reduce its quality. I have seen threads where its been said to use flutter_Image_compress library. But I can't seem to understand that how to implement it with multi image picker.

Multi Image picker

```
Future<List<Asset>> loadAssets() async {
List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();
String error = "No error Detected";

try {
  resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
    maxImages: 10,
    enableCamera: true,
    selectedAssets: images,
    cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
    materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
      actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
      actionBarTitle: "Upload Image",
      allViewTitle: "All Photos",
      useDetailsView: false,
      selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
    ),
  );

  showInSnackBar("loading images");
  print(resultList.length);
  print((await resultList[0].getThumbByteData(122, 100)));
  print((await resultList[0].getByteData()));
  print((await resultList[0].metadata));
  print("loadAssets is called");

} on Exception catch (e) {
  error = e.toString();
  print(error);
}



if (!mounted){
  print("Not mounted");
}
else {
  setState(() {
    images = resultList;
    _error = error;
  });
}

return images;
```

}

Flutter image compress

```
  void compressImage(File file) async {
    final filePath = file.absolute.path;
    final lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf(new RegExp(r'.jp'));
    final splitted = filePath.substring(0, (lastIndex));
    final outPath = "${splitted}_out${filePath.substring(lastIndex)}";

    final compressedImage = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
        filePath,
        outPath,
        minWidth: 1000,
        minHeight: 1000,
        quality: 70);
  }
```

This is what i did

```
Future<List<Asset>> loadAssets() async {
    List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();
    List<File> fileImageArray=[];
    String error = "No error Detected";

    try {

      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 10,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets: images,
        cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
          actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
          actionBarTitle: "Upload Image",
          allViewTitle: "All Photos",
          useDetailsView: false,
          selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
        ),

      );
      resultList.forEach((imageAsset) async {
        final filePath = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(imageAsset.identifier);

        File tempFile = File(filePath);
        if (tempFile.existsSync()) {
          fileImageArray.add(tempFile);
        }
      });
compressImage(fileImageArray);

      showInSnackBar("loading images");
      print(resultList.length);
      print((await resultList[0].getThumbByteData(122, 100)));
      print((await resultList[0].getByteData()));
      print((await resultList[0].metadata));
      print("loadAssets is called");

    } on Exception catch (e) {
      error = e.toString();
      print(error);
    }
    if (!mounted){
      print("Not mounted");
    }
    else {
      setState(() {
        print('Presed1');
        images = resultList;
        _error = error;
      });
    }

    return images;
  }

  void compressImage(fileImageArray) async {
    for(var i in fileImageArray){
      final filePath = i.absolute.path;
      final lastIndex = i.lastIndexOf(new RegExp(r'.jp'));
      final splitted = i.substring(0, (lastIndex));
      final outPath = "${splitted}_out${filePath.substring(lastIndex)}";

      final compressedImage = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
          filePath,
          outPath,
          minWidth: 240,
          minHeight: 240,
          quality: 5);
      setState(() {
   print('pressed2');
        fileImageArray= compressedImage;
      });
    }
```

}

```
onPressed: () async {
                        List<Asset> asst = await loadAssets();
                        if (asst.length == 0) {
                          showAlert("No images selected");
                        }
                        SizedBox(height: 10,);

                        showInSnackBar('Images Successfully loaded');
                        //                 SnackBar snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text('Please wait, we are uploading'));
                        //_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text(value)));
                      }
```

Comment: first, take the image using multi image picker. then you need to convert asset to file.

Comment: Then provide that to your compressedImage function

Comment: please @AbhishekGhaskata check it now. I updated the code. It still isnt compressing image size. What am i doing wrong sir?

Comment: you have to iterate `fileImageArray` via for loop

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata Bhai. Please kindly help me. Dont know how to iterate it :( Trying since yesterday :(

Comment: Now check 
sorry for the late reply

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata can you check updated version i posted. The compressed image method is not getting called;/

Comment: You might need setstate better to debug your code and see the live values of your variable.

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata It does go in compress method. But performs nothing ;/

Comment: use `await compressImage(fileImageArray);` while calling the function.

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata i tried calling it within within loadAssets function.But it didnt work. I have edited how im caliing loadassets. In case thats where problem relies.

Comment: in my mobile the size of image is 128 kb.But when i upload it on cloud firestore. The size gets increased to 238 kb as i download it. Not sure why its not working. Where should i call awaitcompress(fileArrayImage). Where i'm doing it wrong:(

Comment: ```setState(() {
   print('pressed2');
        fileImageArray= compressedImage;
      });```
use different variable here rather than `fileImageArray`.

Comment: Do i need to change the compress Image function to future etc instead of void something.To make it work :(

Comment: No need for it!

Comment: Nothing works :(

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata what i noticed. It is not calling setstate. setState(() {
        
         fileImageArray= compressedImage;
         print('compressedimagesize: ${fileImageArray.lengthSync()}');
      });  I tried changing variable name too.

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata It says await cannot be used. As compressimage is void.

Comment: It's working below Android 13. in 13  Samsung phones it shows blink and does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this to convert List to List

```
List<File> fileImageArray=[];
...
resultList.forEach((imageAsset) async {
    final filePath = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(imageAsset.identifier);
    
    File tempFile = File(filePath);
    if (tempFile.existsSync()) {
        fileImageArray.add(tempFile);
    }
});
```

Give `fileImageArray` to compressImage method.
and iterate it using for loop

```
 void compressImage(fileImageArray) async {
    for(var i in fileImageArray){
    final filePath = i.absolute.path;
    final lastIndex = i.lastIndexOf(new RegExp(r'.jp'));
    final splitted = i.substring(0, (lastIndex));
    final outPath = "${splitted}_out${filePath.substring(lastIndex)}";

    final compressedImage = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
        filePath,
        outPath,
        minWidth: 240,
        minHeight: 240,
        quality: 5);
    setState(() {
      fileImageArray= compressedImage;
    });
   }
  }
```

Comment: First, you have to convert List<Asset> to List<File> then provide to compressImage method

Comment: can u pls tell me what should be srcPath and the target path if i upload my all files to firebase?

Comment: Here there is very good docs from firebase https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/ which might helps you

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Absolute Path is not in development anymore and is not updated with the android v2 embedding. Hence I suggest to use `path_provider` in the below to transform an Asset to File and compress:

```
import 'package:multi_image_picker/multi_image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<File> compressAndUploadAssetImage(Asset asset, Reference ref) async {
        final byteData = await asset.getByteData();
        final tempFile = File("${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/${asset.name}");
        final file = await tempFile.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes),);
        File compressedFile = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(file.path, quality: 70);
        return compressedFile;

    }
```